# How to use destructing in JavaScript — in a helper function which will be passed to a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have this component which takes an id as an attribute:

```
<TeamLogo id={team.id} className="center" />
```

As you can see its a property attached to an object.

So what I came up with is:

```
/* helper function */

  function TeamIdChecker({ id }) {
      if (id === undefined) return <Redirect to="/" />;
      else return team.id;
  }
```

And then i'd like to use it like this:

```
<TeamLogo id={TeamIdChecker(team.id)} className="center" />
```

I didn't try it as I know I'm off!

Thanks my friends in advance!

**Update**
This is my `Team` component:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { getTeam } from "../api";

export default class Team extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    id      : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  state = {
    team: null
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchTeam(this.props.id);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.id !== nextProps.id) {
      this.fetchTeam(nextProps.id);
    }
  }
  fetchTeam = id => {
    this.setState(() => ({ team: null }));
    getTeam(id).then(team => this.setState(() => ({ team })));
  };
  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.state.team);
  }
}
```

This is my `TeamLogo` component:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const logos = {
  // logo key and values
};

TeamLogo.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

TeamLogo.defaultProps = {
  width: "200px"
};

export default function TeamLogo(props) {
  return (
    <svg {...props} x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 125.397 125.397">
      {logos[props.id]}
    </svg>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't want that `<Redirect to="/" />` to be passed as a property to `TeamLogo`, right? I'd just use

```
if (team.id === undefined)
  return <Redirect to="/" />;
else
  return <TeamLogo id={team.id} className="center" />
```

Comment: Actually I guess if the property passed to TeamLogo is `undefined` I'd like Redirect to be kicked off, else the `team.id` just gets passed to `<TeamLogo />`

Comment: So how would I write/declare the variables in the helper function?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you actually want. Do you want to put the logic inside `TeamLogo`? Or do you really need a helper function? Where (and how often) is this snippet used?

Comment: hmm — Great question. What I want to happen is if someone went to went to the URL and entered `/teams/foo` you'd hit the case for a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some conditional rendering

```
function TeamIdChecker({ id }) {
  if (id === undefined) return false;
  else return true;
}
```

then

```
render() { // where your rendering your component
    const { id } = team; // wherever that come from, you destruct it here
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
                {TeamIdChecker(id) ? <TeamLogo id={id} className="center" /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

edit:

or even simpler if this helper function its only used here

```
render() { // where your rendering your component
    const { id } = team; // wherever that come from, you destruct it here
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
                {id !== undefined ? <TeamLogo id={id} className="center" /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```